Question regarding range of an exponential function
This question is in context of the following problem
Find the range of the function
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{2x} - e^x + 1}{e^{2x} + e^x + 1}$$
To find the maxima and minima for the above function i decided to differentiate it, the derivative of the above function ism
$$\frac{-2e^x + 2e^{3x}}{(e^{2x} + e^x + 1)^2}$$
Equating this to $0$, we obtain the value of $x = 0$.
Substituting $x = 0$ in the original function in the place of $x$ gives us the values of $1/3$.
How i am supposed to find the other extrema?
Since there are no other solutions to the derivative when it is 0.
Any help would be appreciated!

Well if there is only one extremum and  it is a non constant function, then it either increases toward infinity or decreases to negative infinity. Thus you must decide if the range is $[1/3,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,1/3]$.

However the thing is the solution to the above question in my textbook is given to be $[1/3, 1)$

Ah, you’re right, it might asymptotically approach some finite value. You could find this by using l’Hopitals rule in the limit as $x\to\infty$

$f(x)$ can be re-written as $\frac{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1-2e^{x}}{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1}$
This means $f(x)=1-\frac{2e^{x}}{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1}$
As $x\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{2e^{x}}{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1} \rightarrow 0$
So $f(x) < 1$ for all $x$.
You have already found that the minimum value is $f(0)=\frac{1}{3}$.
So the range is $[\frac{1}{3},1)$

You are welcome to edit my answer - thought I spotted all the typos (I think too fast and hit "post" before proof reading too often!)

@DavidK - thanks for the edits. Appreciated.
